# How do I connect two android devices instantaneously based on proximity?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

We want to alert users of our Android app when another user of the same app is in close physical proximity, much like how Covid warning apps were able to alert individuals of affected users in their physical proximity. I'm aware that such apps depended on BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) to achieve this functionality, however, the documentation on BLE has been very confusing and does not provide any guides as to how to achieve this. What we want to do is have an instant notification pop up when another user is in proximity, and as such the app must function (I assume) as both an advertiser as well as a scanner? Furthermore since this functionality would need to take place constantly, I'm not sure if we would need to use a foreground service or if there needs to be another approach to this. I've read up on GATT servers but haven't been able to find any examples or implementations that fix the problem of doing both the scanning and advertising at the same time. Would appreciate any help to nudge me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple and Google wrote a [Bluetooth specification](https://blog.google/documents/70/Exposure_Notification_-_Bluetooth_Specification_v1.2.2.pdf/) about how Exposure Notification works.

Due to the power constraints of mobile devices, it is always tricky to get this to work in the background on mobile devices. Therfore Exposure Notification API is part of the OS, but only usable by Public Health Agencies.

With this knowledge, you should be able to build a similar, perhaps not quite as reliable system. At least many BLE Beacon Apps do.

There is a lot of information available on this task:

[Bluetooth Low Energy Advertising](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/bluetooth/ble_advertising)

[Find BLE devices](https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth/ble/find-ble-devices)

[David Young](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1461050/davidgyoung) wrote a nice [Blog](https://www.beaconzone.co.uk/blog/background-scanning-on-android/) posts about this topic.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to my attention. One question though, what do you mean when you say that  the Exposure Notificaton API is only usable by Public Heath Agencies? I believe Google's published their implementation of the API online: https://github.com/google/exposure-notifications-internals/blob/main/exposurenotification/src/main/java/com/google/samples/exposurenotification/ble/advertising/BleAdvertiser.java

Comment: Yes, you can view the source code, but only apps that have been officially published by a "Public Health Agency" can and are allowed to use the Exposure Notification Framework API on your device. This is ensured by Android, which, by the way, has stopped providing this service on 18 September 2023.

In the end, none of this matters to you. You can also implement the technology developed by Apple and Google in your app. The only downside might be a bit of service degradation because the software is running in the context of your app and not at OS level.

Answer (score 2):

Used in my app

This answer takes inspiration from the following websites :
https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth/ble/ble-overview
https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth/ble/find-ble-devices
https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth/ble/connect-gatt-server
https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth/ble/transfer-ble-data
https://medium.com/@martijn.van.welie/making-android-ble-work-part-1-a736dcd53b02
By Martijn van Welie

https://bignerdranch.com/blog/bluetooth-low-energy-on-android-part-1/
https://bignerdranch.com/blog/bluetooth-low-energy-on-android-part-2/
By Andrew Lunsford

For further information you can consult the aforementioned websites

step 1
The BLE app provides an activity (Game1BleActivity) to connect to Bluetooth device.
Based on user input, this activity communicates with a Service called BluetoothLeService,
which interacts with the BLE device via the BLE API.
The communication is performed using a bound service which allows the activity to connect to the
BluetoothLeService and call functions to connect to the devices.
The BluetoothLeService needs a Binder implementation that provides access to the service for the activity.

step 2
The BluetoothLeService needs a Binder implementation that provides access to the service for the activity.

```
override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder {
        return binder
}
inner class LocalBinder : Binder() {
        fun getService() : BluetoothLeService {
            return this@BluetoothLeService
        }
}
```

step 3
A client binds to a service by calling bindService().
When it does, it must provide an implementation of ServiceConnection, which monitors
the connection with the service.
The return value of bindService() indicates whether the requested service exists and
whether the client is permitted access to it.

```
// Code to manage Service lifecycle.
var bluetoothService : BluetoothLeService? = null
private val serviceConnection: ServiceConnection = object : ServiceConnection {
    override fun onServiceConnected(
        componentName: ComponentName,
        service: IBinder
    ) {
        bluetoothService = (service as BluetoothLeService.LocalBinder).getService()
        bluetoothService?.let { bluetooth ->
            // call functions on service to check connection and connect to devices
            if (!bluetooth.initialize(context)) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize Bluetooth")
                finish()
            }
            /*
            BluetootLeService -> step 7 -> BluetootLeService
            */
            bluetooth.setupServer()
            bluetooth.startAdvertising()
            /*
            step 10 -> BluetootLeService
             */
            // perform device scanning
            bluetooth.scan()
        }
    }
override fun onServiceDisconnected(componentName: ComponentName) {
        bluetoothService = null
    }
}
```

step 4
Once the service is bound to, it needs to access the BluetoothAdapter.
It should check that the adapter is available on the device.
The following example wraps this setup code in an initialize() function that returns a Boolean
value indicating success.

```
fun initialize(context:Context): Boolean {
    // Initializes a Bluetooth adapter.  For API level 18 and above, get a reference to
    // BluetoothAdapter through BluetoothManager.
    val bluetoothManager = getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
    bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.adapter
    if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to obtain a BluetoothAdapter.")
        return false
    }
    /*
    step 6 (1 sc) Scan settings
     */
    scanner = bluetoothAdapter!!.getBluetoothLeScanner()
    scanSettings = ScanSettings.Builder()
        .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER)
        .setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES)
        .setMatchMode(ScanSettings.MATCH_MODE_AGGRESSIVE)
        .setNumOfMatches(ScanSettings.MATCH_NUM_ONE_ADVERTISEMENT)
        .setReportDelay(0L)
        .build()
    // other initializations
    ctext = context
    //
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    // Create the NotificationChannel.
    val name = ctext.getString(R.string.notification_channel_name)
    val descriptionText = ctext.getString(R.string.notification_channel_description)
    val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
    NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = ctext.getString(R.string.notification_channel_name)
    val mChannel = NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, name, importance)
    mChannel.description = descriptionText
    // Register the channel with the system. You can't change the importance
    // or other notification behaviors after this.
    val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
    //
    return true
}
```

step 5
The activity calls this function within its ServiceConnection implementation.
Handling a false return value from the initialize() function depends on your application.
You could show an error message to the user indicating that the current device
does not support the Bluetooth operation or disable any features that require Bluetooth to work.
In the following example, finish() is called on the activity to send the user back to the previous screen.

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    //
    registerReceiver(gattUpdateReceiver, makeGattUpdateIntentFilter())
    //
    // check Bluetooth Ble Permissions
    //
    if (!btAdapter.isEnabled) {
                val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
                enableBtResultLauncher.launch(enableBtIntent)
            } else {
                /*
                step 3 
                */
                if (bluetoothService == null) {
                    val gattServiceIntent = Intent(this, BluetoothLeService::class.java)
                    bindService(gattServiceIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
                }
                else
                {
                /*
                    step 5 
                */
                if (!bluetoothService!!.initialize(this)) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize Bluetooth")
                        finish()
                    }
                /*
                step 7
                */
                bluetoothService!!.setupServer()
                bluetoothService!!.startAdvertising()
                /*
                step 10 
                */
                // perform device scanning
                bluetoothService!!.scan()
                //
                bluetoothService!!.activityInActiveState()
        // other 
}
//
private fun makeGattUpdateIntentFilter(): IntentFilter {
    return IntentFilter().apply {
        addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED)
        addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED)
        addAction(BluetoothLeService.MESSAGE_FROM_GATT_SERVER)
    }
}
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    if (bluetoothService != null)
        {
        bluetoothService!!.sendMessage("I'M DISCONNECTING")
        bluetoothService!!.stopAdvertising()
        bluetoothService!!.stopScanner()
        //
        bluetoothService!!.activityInPausedState()
        }
    unregisterReceiver(gattUpdateReceiver)
}
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    bluetoothService!!.stopServer()
    bluetoothService!!.disconnect()
    // 
}
```

step 6 (1 sc) Scan settings : see step 4

step 7 (1 gatt server) setup Gatt Server : see step 3

```
private var mGattServer: BluetoothGattServer? = null
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
fun setupServer() {
    if (mGattServer == null) {
        val bluetoothManager = getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
        mGattServer = bluetoothManager.openGattServer(this, gattServerCallback)
        val service = BluetoothGattService(
            SERVICE_UUID,
            BluetoothGattService.SERVICE_TYPE_PRIMARY
        )
        // add a Characteristic that will allow Clients to send a message to the Server.
        val writeCharacteristic = BluetoothGattCharacteristic(
            CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE,
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE
        )
        service.addCharacteristic(writeCharacteristic)
        //
        mGattServer!!.addService(service)
        //
    }
}
```

step 8 (2 Gatt Server) : what to do when a write request is received

```
private val gattServerCallback = object : BluetoothGattServerCallback()
{
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onCharacteristicWriteRequest(
        device: BluetoothDevice?,
        requestId: Int,
        characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic,
        preparedWrite: Boolean,
        responseNeeded: Boolean,
        offset: Int,
        value: ByteArray?
    ) {
        super.onCharacteristicWriteRequest(
            device,
            requestId,
            characteristic,
            preparedWrite,
            responseNeeded,
            offset,
            value
        )
        if (characteristic.uuid == CHARACTERISTIC_UUID) {
            mGattServer!!.sendResponse(device, requestId, BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS, 0, null)
            /*
            // reverse the value of the Characteristic to differentiate the response from the request
            val length: Int = value!!.size
            val reversed = ByteArray(length)
            for (i in 0 until length) {
                reversed[i] = value.get(length - (i + 1))
            }
            // After setting the Characteristic’s new value, we tell mGattServer to notify all
            // connected devices for this characteristic
            characteristic.value = reversed
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                mGattServer!!.notifyCharacteristicChanged(device!!, characteristic, false, reversed)
            }
            else {
                mGattServer!!.notifyCharacteristicChanged(device, characteristic, false)
            }
             */
            // inserire qui visualizzazione messaggio
            broadcastUpdate(MESSAGE_FROM_GATT_SERVER)
            messageFromGattServer =  value!!.toString(Charsets.UTF_8)
            //
            if (activityIsPaused)
            {
                notifyMessageFromGattServer()
            }
        }
    }
}
// TTS
var tTS1: TextToSpeech? = null
var toSpeak: String? = null
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
fun notifyMessageFromGattServer ()  {
    if (messageFromGattServer != "I'M DISCONNECTING")
    {
        // message processing, for example sending notification and speaking the message
         // Create an explicit intent for an Activity in your app.
        val fullScreenIntent = Intent(this, Game1BleActivity::class.java).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        }
        //  the activity from a service
        val fullScreenPendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, fullScreenIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        //
        val builder = Notification.Builder(ctext,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.heart)
            .setContentTitle(deviceEnabledUserName)
            .setContentText(messageFromGattServer)
            // Set the intent that fires when the user taps the notification.
            .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true)
            .setLargeIcon(bitmap1)
            .setStyle(Notification.BigPictureStyle()
                .bigPicture(bitmap1))
        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(ctext)) {
            // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define.
            notify(1, builder.build())
        }
        //
        tTS1 = TextToSpeech(ctext) { status ->
            if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                tTS1!!.speak(
                    messageFromGattServer,
                    TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,
                    null,
                    getString(R.string.prova_tts)
                )
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ctext, status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

step 9 (3 Gatt Server) Start Advertising : see step 3

```
private var mBluetoothLeAdvertiser: BluetoothLeAdvertiser? = null
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
fun startAdvertising() {
    if (mBluetoothLeAdvertiser == null) {
        mBluetoothLeAdvertiser = bluetoothAdapter!!.getBluetoothLeAdvertiser()
        if (mBluetoothLeAdvertiser == null) {
            return
        }
        val settings = AdvertiseSettings.Builder()
            .setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_BALANCED)
            .setConnectable(true)
            .setTimeout(0)
            .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_LOW)
            .build()
        val parcelUuid = ParcelUuid(SERVICE_UUID)
        val data = AdvertiseData.Builder()
            .setIncludeDeviceName(true)
            .addServiceUuid(parcelUuid)
            .build()
        mBluetoothLeAdvertiser!!.startAdvertising(settings, data, mAdvertiseCallback)
    }
}
//
private val mAdvertiseCallback: AdvertiseCallback = object : AdvertiseCallback() {
    override fun onStartSuccess(settingsInEffect: AdvertiseSettings) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Peripheral advertising started.")
    }
    override fun onStartFailure(errorCode: Int) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Peripheral advertising failed: $errorCode")
    }
}
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
fun stopAdvertising() {
    if (mBluetoothLeAdvertiser != null) {
        mBluetoothLeAdvertiser!!.stopAdvertising(mAdvertiseCallback)
    }
}
```

step 10 (3 sc) Bluetooth scan : see step 3

```
private var mScanning = false
var devicesArrayList: ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> = ArrayList()
private lateinit var deviceAddressFound: String
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
fun scan() {
    if (!mScanning)
    {
        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            mScanning = false
            scanner.stopScan(scanCallback)
            // the scan  did not find any devices so we check if there are devices connected
            // to the gatt server to connect their gatt
            val bluetoothDevicesConnectedToTheGattServerList = devicesConnected(GATT_SERVER)
            if (!bluetoothDevicesConnectedToTheGattServerList.isEmpty())
            {
                device = bluetoothDevicesConnectedToTheGattServerList.first()
                // search for image of the device user to send any notifications
                searchForImageOfTheDeviceUser()
                //
                bluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, bluetoothGattCallback, TRANSPORT_LE)
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD)
        //
        var filters: MutableList<ScanFilter> = ArrayList()
        val filter = ScanFilter.Builder()
            .setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid.fromString(SERVICE_UUID.toString()))
            .build()
        filters.add(filter)
        //
        mScanning = true
        scanner.startScan(filters, scanSettings, scanCallback)
    }
}
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
fun stopScanner() {
    if (mScanning) {
        scanner.stopScan(scanCallback)
        mScanning = false
    }
}
```

step 11 (4 sc) Bluetooth scan callback

```
private val scanCallback: ScanCallback = object : ScanCallback() {
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult) {
        val device: BluetoothDevice = result.getDevice()
        // ...do whatever you want with this found device
        if (!devicesArrayList.contains(device)) {
            devicesArrayList.add(device)
            deviceAddressFound = device.address!!
            connect(deviceAddressFound)
        }
    }
    override fun onBatchScanResults(results: List<ScanResult?>?) {
        // Ignore for now
    }
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onScanFailed(errorCode: Int) {
        // Ignore for now
    }
}
```

step 12
Once the BluetoothService is initialized, it can connect to the BLE device.
The activity needs to send the device address to the service so it can initiate the connection.
The service will first call getRemoteDevice() on the BluetoothAdapter to access the device.
If the adapter is unable to find a device with that address, getRemoteDevice()
throws an IllegalArgumentException.

```
private var bluetoothGatt: BluetoothGatt? = null
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
fun connect(address: String): Boolean {
    if (mScanning) {
        scanner.stopScan(scanCallback)
        mScanning = false
    }
    bluetoothAdapter?.let { adapter ->
        try {
            if (bluetoothGatt == null)
            {
                device = adapter.getRemoteDevice(address)
                // search for image of the device user to send any notifications
                searchForImageOfTheDeviceUser()
                // connect to the GATT server on the device
                /*
                step 15
                 */
                bluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, bluetoothGattCallback, TRANSPORT_LE)
            }
            return true
        } catch (exception: IllegalArgumentException) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Device not found with provided address.")
            return false
        }

    } ?: run {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized")
        return false
    }
}
```

step 13
Once the activity tells the service which device to connect to and the service connects to the device,
the service needs to connect to the GATT server on the BLE device.
This connection requires a BluetoothGattCallback to receive notifications about the connection state,
service discovery, characteristic reads, and characteristic notifications.
This topic focuses on the connection state notifications.
See Transfer BLE data for how to perform service discovery, characteristic reads, and request
characteristic notifications.
The onConnectionStateChange() function is triggered when the connection to the device’s
GATT server changes.
The callback is defined in the Service class so it can be used with the BluetoothDevice once
the service connects to it.

```
private var connectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED
private lateinit var device: BluetoothDevice
private var service: BluetoothGattService? = null
private lateinit var characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic
private var mConnected: Boolean = false
private var mInitialized: Boolean = false
private val bluetoothGattCallback = object : BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onConnectionStateChange(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int, newState: Int) {
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            // successfully connected to the GATT Server
            /*
            Game1BleActivity -> step 17
             */
            // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
            gatt!!.discoverServices()
        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            // disconnected from the GATT Server
            connectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED)
            mConnected = false
            gatt!!.close()
        }

    }
```

step 14
When the server connects or disconnects from the GATT server, it needs to notify the activity of the new state.
There are several ways to accomplish this.
We use broadcasts to send the information from the service to activity.
The service declares a function to broadcast the new state.
This function takes in an action string which is passed to an Intent object before being broadcast to the system.

```
private fun broadcastUpdate(action: String) {
    val intent = Intent(action)
    sendBroadcast(intent)
}
```

step 15 : see step 12
Once the BluetoothGattCallback is declared, the service can use the BluetoothDevice
object from the connect() function to connect to the GATT service on the device.
The connectGatt() function is used.
This requires a Context object, an autoConnect boolean flag, and the BluetoothGattCallback.
In this example, the app is directly connecting to the BLE device, so false is passed for autoConnect.

step 16 -> BluetootLeService
Once the service broadcasts the connection updates, the activity needs to implement a BroadcastReceiver.
Register this receiver when setting up the activity, and unregister it when the activity is leaving the screen.
By listening for the events from the service, the activity is able to update the user interface
based on the current connection state with the BLE device.
In Transfer BLE data, the BroadcastReceiver is also used to communicate the service discovery
as well as the characteristic data from the device.

```
private val gattUpdateReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        when (intent.action) {
            BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED -> {
                mConnected = true
                // if MultipleAdvertisement is not supported the device name is not available
                if (bluetoothService!!.getDeviceEnabledName() != null)
                    { deviceEnabledName = bluetoothService!!.getDeviceEnabledName() }
                    else
                    { deviceEnabledName = "mancante" }
                //
                enableTransmitToConnectedBluetooth()
            }
            BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED -> {
                mConnected = false
                disableTransmitToDisconnectedBluetooth()
            }
            BluetoothLeService.MESSAGE_FROM_GATT_SERVER -> {
                messageFromGattServer = bluetoothService!!.getMessageFromGattServer()
                if (messageFromGattServer == "I'M DISCONNECTING")
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    // update the user interface
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

step 17 service discovery: see step 13
The first thing to do once you connect to the GATT Server on the BLE device is
to perform service discovery.
This provides information about the services available on the remote device as well
as the service characteristics and their descriptors.
Once the service successfully connects to the device
(indicated by the appropriate call to the onConnectionStateChange() function of the
BluetoothGattCallback), the discoverServices() function queries the information from the BLE device.
The service needs to override the onServicesDiscovered() function in the BluetoothGattCallback.
This function is called when the device reports on its available services.

step 18
This function is part of bluetoothGattCallback and is called when the device reports on its available services.

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int) {
    if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
        /*
        If the discovery services was successful, we can now negotiate a larger MTU than the
        default (23 bytes).
        */
        gatt!!.requestMtu(256)
    } else {
        disconnect()
        Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: $status")
    }
}
```

step 19
These functions are part of bluetoothGattCallback.
If the discovery services was successful and the MTU has been agreed,
we can now look for our Characteristic.
Since we know the full UUID of both the Service and the Characteristic,
we can access them directly.

```
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onMtuChanged(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, mtu: Int, status: Int) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            if (gatt != null) {
                service = gatt.getService(SERVICE_UUID)
                if (service != null) {
                    characteristic = service!!.getCharacteristic(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID)
                    /*
                    Now that we have found our Characteristic, we need to set the write type and
                    enable notifications.
                    mInitialized is used to signify that our Characteristic is fully ready for use.
                    Without reaching this point, the Characteristic would not have the correct write type
                    or notify us when there is a change.
                    Make sure to set this to false when disconnecting from the GATT server.
                     */
                    characteristic.writeType = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT
                    mInitialized = gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true)
                }
            }
            //
            connectionState = STATE_CONNECTED
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED)
            mConnected = true
            //
        }
        else {
            disconnect()
            Log.w(TAG, "onMtuChanged received: $status")
        }
    }

    override fun onCharacteristicRead(
        gatt: BluetoothGatt,
        characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic,
        value: ByteArray,
        status: Int
    ) {  }

    override fun onCharacteristicChanged(
        gatt: BluetoothGatt,
        characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic,
        value: ByteArray
    ) {
        super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic, value)
    }
}
```

step 20
One important step when dealing with Bluetooth connections is to close the connection when you are finished with it.
To do this, call the close() function on the BluetoothGatt object.
In the following example, the service holds the reference to the BluetoothGatt.
When the activity unbinds from the service, the connection is closed to avoid draining the device battery.

```
override fun onUnbind(intent: Intent?): Boolean {
    close()
    return super.onUnbind(intent)
}
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private fun close() {
    bluetoothGatt?.let { gatt ->
        gatt.close()
        bluetoothGatt = null
    }
    // TTS
    if (tTS1 != null) {
        tTS1!!.stop()
        tTS1!!.shutdown()
    }
}
```

step 21
set the value on the Characteristic and our message will be sent

This answer to the question was very laborious. I hope it's useful