# Is there a way to convert the BLE GATT callback from asynchronous to synchronous?

Tags: android, kotlin, concurrency, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am new to Android development and concurrency and I am trying to build a Kotlin app, where it connects to a [BLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_Low_Energy) device and reads characteristics using `readCharacteristic` function and use the value read. The issue is, I want the main thread (or whatever thread the `readCharacteristic` is called in) to block and wait for a the callback. This is because I need this value to be displayed and used for calculation.

Currently all BLE operations are put in a queue so that only one operation will do work at a time. The queue is implemented as the following.

```java
object ConnectionManager {
    private val deviceGattMap = ConcurrentHashMap<BluetoothDevice, BluetoothGatt>()
    private val operationQueue = ConcurrentLinkedQueue<BleOperationType>()
    private var pendingOperation: BleOperationType? = null
    private var connecting = false

    @Synchronized
    private fun enqueueOperation(operation: BleOperationType) {
        operationQueue.add(operation)
        if (pendingOperation == null) {
            doNextOperation()
        }
    }

    @Synchronized
    private fun signalEndOfOperation() {
        pendingOperation = null
        if (operationQueue.isNotEmpty()) {
            doNextOperation()
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Synchronized
    private fun doNextOperation() {
        if (pendingOperation != null) {
            Log.e(
                "ConnectionManager",
                "doNextOperation() called when an operation is pending! Aborting."
            )
            return
        }

        val operation = operationQueue.poll() ?: run {
            Log.i("ConnectionManager", "Operation queue empty, returning")
            return
        }

        pendingOperation = operation

        if (operation is Connect) {
            connecting = true
            operation.device.connectGatt(operation.context, false, gattCallback)

            while (connecting) {
            }
            return
        }

        val gatt = deviceGattMap[operation.device]
            ?: this@ConnectionManager.run {

                Log.e(
                    "ConnectionManager",
                    "Not connected to ${operation.device.address}! Aborting $operation operation."
                )
                signalEndOfOperation()
                return
            }

        when (operation) {

            is Disconnect -> {
                gatt.close()
                deviceGattMap.remove(operation.device)
                signalEndOfOperation()
            }

            is CharacteristicWrite -> {
                gatt.findCharacteristic(operation.characteristicUuid)?.let { characteristic ->
                    characteristic.value = operation.value
                    characteristic.writeType = operation.writeType
                    gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic)
                } ?: run {
                    Log.e(
                        "ConnectionManager",
                        "Characteristic ${operation.characteristicUuid} not found!"
                    )
                    signalEndOfOperation()
                }
            }

            is CharacteristicRead -> {
                gatt.findCharacteristic(operation.characteristicUuid)?.let { characteristic ->
                    gatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic)

                } ?: this@ConnectionManager.run {
                    Log.e(
                        "ConnectionManager",
                        "Characteristic ${operation.characteristicUuid} not found!"
                    )
                    signalEndOfOperation()
                }
            }

            is WriteDescriptor -> {
                .......
            }
        } is ......
    }

}
```

This is the [GATT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Attribute_Profile_(ATT)) callback:

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private val gattCallback = object : BluetoothGattCallback() {
        override fun onConnectionStateChange(gatt: BluetoothGatt, status: Int, newState: Int) {
            Log.w("BluetoothGattCallback", "Connection state changed: $status")
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {

                if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                    deviceGattMap[gatt.device] = gatt
                    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
                        deviceGattMap[gatt.device]?.discoverServices()
                    }
                    connecting = false
                } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTING) {
                    disconnect(gatt.device)
                }
            } else {
                connecting = false

                Log.w("BluetoothGattCallback", "Error $status")
                if (pendingOperation is Connect) {
                    signalEndOfOperation()
                }
                //disconnect(gatt.device)
            } // Todo handle errors
        }

        override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt, status: Int) {

            with(gatt) {
                if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                    Log.w("BluetoothGattCallback", "Discovered ${services.size} services")
                    if (services.isEmpty()) {
                        Log.i(
                            "PrintGattTable",
                            "No services characteristics available, Call DiscoverServices() first?"
                        )
                        return
                    }
                    else {
                        services.forEach { service ->
                            val characteristicsTable = service.characteristics.joinToString(
                                separator = "\n | --",
                                prefix = "| --"
                            ) {
                                it.uuid.toString()
                            }
                            Log.i(
                                "PrintGattTable",
                                "\n Services ${service.uuid} \n Characteristics ${characteristicsTable}"
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    ConnectionManager.requestMtu(gatt.device, 517)
                } else {
                    Log.e("BluetoothGattCallback", "Service discovery failed with status $status")
                    disconnect(device)
                }
            }
            if (pendingOperation is Connect) {
                signalEndOfOperation()
            }
        }

        override fun onMtuChanged(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, mtu: Int, status: Int) {
            Log.i("MTU", "ATT MTU changed to $mtu, success ${status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS}")
            if (pendingOperation is MtuRequest) {
                signalEndOfOperation()
            }
        }

        override fun onCharacteristicRead(
            gatt: BluetoothGatt,
            characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic,
            status: Int
        ) {

            with(characteristic) {

                when (status) {
                    BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS -> {
                        if (characteristic.uuid.toString() == BatteryCharacteristicUUID) {
                            Log.i("BluetoothGattCallback", "Read characteristic $uuid:\n${
                                value.joinToString(
                                    separator = " ",
                                    prefix = "0x"
                                ) { String.format("%02X", it) }
                            } and \n ${value[0].toUInt()}"
                            )
                        }
                        else {
                            var light : MutableList<UInt> = mutableListOf()
                            for (i in 0..value.size-1 step 4) {
                                light.add(
                                ((value[i].toUInt() and 0xFFu) shl 24) or
                                ((value[i + 1].toUInt() and 0xFFu) shl 16) or
                                ((value[i + 2].toUInt() and 0xFFu) shl 8) or
                                (value[i+ 3].toUInt() and 0xFFu))
                            }

                            Log.i("BluetoothGattCallback", "Read characteristic $uuid:\n${
                                value.joinToString(
                                    separator = " ",
                                    prefix = "0x"
                                ) { String.format("%02X", it) }
                            }" +
                                    " and \n ${light}"
                            )
                        }
                    }

                    BluetoothGatt.GATT_READ_NOT_PERMITTED -> {
                    }
                    else -> {
                        Log.e("BluetoothGattCallback", "Characteristic read failed for $uuid, error: $status")
                    }
                }
            }
            if (pendingOperation is CharacteristicRead) {
                signalEndOfOperation()
            }
        }

    }
```

When to read the characteristics I call `ConnectionManager.readCharacteristic()` which in turn checks if characteristic is readable and if device is connected then adds the operation to the queue.

When calling

```
ConnectionManager.readCharacteristic(device, char)

Log.i("Tag", $char.value)
```

The output is null since the Log statement is executed before the callback for the read is executed.

Is there a way to block the thread without time delay or maybe it is not a good idea to block and should look into a solution involving future or promises? If so, any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: You're working in Kotlin.  The solution is coroutines, not futures or promises.

Comment: You don’t want to block the main thread—this freezes the phone up, making it unresponsive and at risk of an ANR crash. If the main thread needs to wait for something before you can show your UI, and it’s long enough to be noticeable, you should show a loading indicator or loading screen in your UI rather than blocking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, if possible, it is better to follow the guidelines suggested by the Google site, i.e., to use a service and notify the activity with Broadcast updates.

See *[Connect to a GATT server](https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth/ble/connect-gatt-server)*.

For details, see my answer [How do I connect two android devices instantaneously based on proximity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77839355/how-do-i-connect-two-android-devices-instantaneously-based-on-proximity/77839771#77839771).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35786552)

Comment: Thanks for reporting, but in this case the essential part of the answer is very simple: use a service and notify the activity with Broadcast updates.
Other additions, in my opinion, could unnecessarily complicate the answer itself

Comment: Re *"follow the lines"*: Do you mean *"follow the guidelines"*?